# Click on an LI and send the value of the span on it and send it as the value of an input with Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to click on an LI, and have the value of that span of each LI.
but I don't have an access to the value of the spans and when I click the value of LIs selects not spans.

here is my code :

```js
$('li.inliner').on('click',function(){
  var content = $(this).text();
  $('#MySearchBox').val(content);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li class="inliner">price <span>1000</span></li>
  <li class="inliner">Another <span>2000</span></li>
</ul>
<br>
<input type='text' id="MySearchBox" name="MySearchBox"/>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this.

```js
$("li.inliner").on("click", function() {
  var content = $(this).find('span').text().trim();
  $("#MySearchBox").val(content);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
    <li class="inliner">price <span>1000</span></li>
    <li class="inliner">Another <span>2000</span></li>

</ul>
<br>
    <input type='text' id="MySearchBox" name="MySearchBox"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Small Change in your selector. Thats it.

```js
$('li.inliner').on('click',function(){

var content= $(this).find('span').html();
$('#MySearchBox').val(content);
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
    <li class="inliner">price <span>1000</span></li>
    <li class="inliner">Another <span>2000</span></li>

</ul>
<br>
    <input type='text' id="MySearchBox" name="MySearchBox"/>
```